# Throwing Custom Exception with HTTP Response From Spring Validator

Tags: spring

I have implemented a custom Validator in Spring which is called inside an overridden Jackson de-serializer. If validation fails, I want the HTTP response code to be a 403 Forbidden as defined in my ControllerAdvice.

However, the response is always 400 Bad Request.

```
    public class InterceptedDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Object> implements ResolvableDeserializer
{   
    public InterceptedDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer)
    {
        super(Object.class);
        this.defaultDeserializer = defaultDeserializer;
    }

   @Override public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, My403Exception
    {
        this.classFieldValidator = ServletUtils.findWebApplicationContext().getBean(ClassFieldValidator.class);

        Object deserializedObject = defaultDeserializer.deserialize(jp, ctxt);

        Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(deserializedObject, deserializedObject.getClass().getName());
        classFieldValidator.validate(deserializedObject, errors);

        if(errors.hasErrors() || errors.hasFieldErrors()){
            throw new My403Exception("No funny business");
        }

        return deserializedObject;
    }
}
```

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationControllerAdvice {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValidationControllerAdvice.class);
    private final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(My403Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public ErrorResponse my403Exception(My403Exception e) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
        errorResponse.setErrorCode("my403");
        errorResponse.setDescription(e.getMessage());
        errorResponse.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String eStackTrace = sw.toString();
        log.error("My403 error message: " + e.getMessage() + "\nException Class:" + e.getClass() + "\nStack Trace:" + eStackTrace);
        return errorResponse;
    }

}
```

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
public class My403Exception extends RuntimeException{

    private String message;

    public My403Exception(String message) {
        super(message);
        this.message = message;
    }

    public My403Exception() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/thing")
public void createmyThing(@RequestParam(value = "thing") String thing, @RequestBody() @Valid MyThing thing) throws My403Exception {
    thingService.createThing(thing);
}
```

Comment: Is it actually hitting your ControllerAdvice method?

Comment: It is only hitting the controller advice when I validate a direct field inside a deserialized object, never when it deserializes a field within an object inside an object.